# How can I retrieve the new data in real time using Python whenever my Firestore is updated?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on this Python project where I want my code to execute a certain function whenever my FireStore is updated. Below is my attempt to print the newly added data.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import threading


cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db=firestore.client()

# Create an Event for notifying main thread.
delete_done = threading.Event()

# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print(u'New Confession: ')
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            result=db.collection('Confessions').document(change.document.id).get()
            print(result.to_dict())

col_query = db.collection(u'Confessions')

# Watch the collection query
query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

I have followed Firebase's documentation to view changes between snapshots. Here is the link to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) and below is a screenshot to my firestore.

[image]

To summarise my attempt is to retrieve new 'confessions' in real time and display it or write it to a file.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. What isn't working about it when you run it and step through it in a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make script keep running. Add this at the end of your code:

```
while True:
    print('', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

For reference, here's the full code:

```
# Create an Event for notifying main thread.
delete_done = threading.Event()

# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print(u'New Users: ')
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            result=db.collection('users').document(change.document.id).get()
            print(result.to_dict())

col_query = db.collection(u'users')

# Watch the collection query
query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)

while True:
    print('', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Another solution. Use the `-i` option at the terminal:

```
python -i main.py
```

Comment: That was the missing piece. I just have to make the script to keep running. Thank you @Marc!